# SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor : How to remember some data between logging request and response?

Tags: spring-integration

I am using SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor to log web service request and response. When logging response, I need to use a data that only available in request.

How do I remember that data ?

I tried to use messageContext to get the request, but the method handleResponse, handleRequest are final.

I am thinking about using ThreadLocal. Is it safe ? ie, the handleRequest and handleResponse will be run on the same thread, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ThreadLocal` is fine; be sure to `remove()` it when processing the reponse (and if an exception occurs).

Comment: Thank you Gary :-)

Comment: But I think it is just a work around. What we need here is the messageContext to access request, response when needed. and the handleRequest, handleReponse have messageContext already. I think Spring Integration should not make handleRequest, handleResponse final. Why make them final? It like killing the most powerful feature of Java : inheritance. Hope they change it in future.